# How to prevent Matplotlib annotation out of the frame of the plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, annotations

I try to label my bar with its y-axis values (`yy`) in `rotation=90` but some low values are out of the frame My `xx` is the x-axis value from 0 to 5.

```
ax_actsumbar.annotate('{:.2e}'.format(yy), xy=(xx+0.5, yy), xycoords='data', \
                      rotation=90)
```

[image]

How to limit the annotation in the frame? So the annotation of every bar is next to the bar but not go over the frame. I found `.get_window_extent` and tried apply it but didn't work yet.

```
_actsumbar = ax_actsumbar.annotate('{:.2e}'.format(yy), xy=(xx+0.5, yy), xycoords='data', \
                                   rotation=90)
_actsumbar = ax_actsumbar.annotate('{:.2e}'.format(yy), xy=(xx+0.5, yy), \
                                   xycoords=_actsumbar.get_window_extent, rotation=90)
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to tell the requirement you have. E.g. in order to keep the annotations inside the axes, just putting their lower corner at 0 in data coordinates works. But is that what you're after? Nobody knows.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I update the question. Yes, may you guide about how to set the corner of data coordinate? I am checking the document, the argument of data coordinate seems to be something like ‘figure points’ or ‘axes points’. Is this what you mention about?

Comment: What I mean is you need to tell what you want to achieve. Where should the label be? In order to get them into the plot just set the y coordinate to zero, `xy=(xx+0.5, 0), va="bottom"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the location based on the height of each bar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt        

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2.09e+12, 3.2e+09, 6.41e+10, 6.34e+11, 1.75e+07, 3.29e+09]
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'black']

split_point = max(y) / 4.0
bars = plt.bar(x, y, color=colors)

for bar, color in zip(bars, colors):
    bbox = bar.get_bbox()
    va, y = ('top', bbox.y1) if bbox.y1 > split_point else ('bottom', 0)
    plt.annotate(' {:.2e}'.format(bbox.y1), xy=(bbox.x1+0.05, y), xycoords='data', rotation=90, va=va, color=color)

plt.show()
```

This calculates the highest bar and aligns anything less than a 1/4 height to be aligned to the bottom.

[image: matplotlib showing adaptive aligment]

Comment: May you explain about `bbox.y1`? What is `y1` here?

Comment: `bbox` is a rectangle, so you get bottom left and top right coordinates. They name them `x0, y0` and `x1, y1`